# Populating a Datagrid with information retrieved from a Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, metadata-api, fuel-sdk, data

I used the base app generator to create an app within which I have a Fuelux Datagrid that I would like to populate with information from a data extension.

I followed the sample here:https://github.com/adamalex/fuelux-dgdemo and was able to get an idea of how this works. I know I will need to use some kind of URL to connect to the Exacttarget API but I am a bit fuzzy about how to do that.

I found documentation on how to retrieve information using the Fuel SDKS here: https://code.exacttarget.com/sdks/fuel-sdk-interacting-data-extension

but since I am not using an SDK, is there another way to retrieve the information from the data extension?

Comment: Would you be open to a SOAP call?

Comment: Yes, although I've never used one before so I do not know the syntax. Is there documentation somewhere for this? @Timothy

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link for SOAP within ET.  http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/soap_api_best_practices/

It is assuming you have some knowledge how SOAP works, so you may need to brush up on that first.